# Sharepoint Search not displaying values from a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, search, search-results, enterprise-search

In my SharePoint 2013 environment, I am trying to display a value in my custom search results from a column in my SharePoint list.

I am working on a customized 'Default Item' search template in SharePoint Designer, to display the custom search results.

I did the following steps:

- Created a Custom SharePoint List in a subsite, added dummy data to the list
- Ran the Full Search crawl in the Central Admin so that the data I added could be indexed or crawled.
- Here, I want the value in the search result to be coming from this PostURL column in the list:
  [image]
- Then I went to the Managed property in my Site Collection Administration (as I know the a managed property needs to be created for a column in order to be displayed in search result) as shown in the attached screenshot below

[image]

- In the managed property, I searched for the column name 'PostUrl' from my custom list as I wanted the data from this column to be displayed in the search result the and could not find it (looks like SharePoint doesn't automatically convert the list column to a managed property)
- I then manually created a Managed Property against my column as shown below:
  [image]

The column name is prefixed with ows_PostURL under the 'Mapped Crawled Properties'

I then went back to my SharePoint designer, and added the Property Name 'PostURL' in the ManagedPropertyMapping section as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

And then I updated the Div tag in the search template to have the Managed Property name like so so it could appear in the search result.

[image]

For some reason, the value from that SharePoint column 'PostURL' is not appearing in my search result even after I created a managed property for that column.

Am I missing something here? Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: If i remember it correct, SharePoint does not create managed properties out of standard added list columns. If you create a site column and use it in your list instead, SharePoint will create a managed property (after a full crawl ofc). And i think that a incremental crawl creates the crawled property, which you have to manually map to a managed property and AFTER that, run a full crawl, otherwise SharePoint won't know that you mapped the managed property to your crawled property, so try to run a full crawl again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Christoffer. In this scenario, I have created a column in a custom SharePoint list, I haven't created any site column.

Comment: Are you getting correct values for `Title` & `Description` columns ? Also have you tried `Re-index` the list?

Comment: After creating the MP you have to run another full crawl. Also, is the site collection that you created the MP the same one that has the Display Template? Try a query like PublishUrl:http*.

Comment: Thanks Yayati for your reply. Yes, I am able to get the values of 'Title' and 'Description' in my search result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through your question(which I must say well described),  I figured out that only thing which you have to do is to create a custom `Result Type` and specify the display template(which you have already created) which this custom result type will be using.

Following are the steps to create custom `Result Type`.

1. Go to **Site Settings** --> **Search Result Types** --> **New Result Type**
2. Enter `Name` for result type.
3. Select the `Display Template` which you have created.
4. Click **OK**.

Lastly, make following changes to your `Search Result` web part.

1. Edit `Search Result` web part in browser.
2. In **Display Template** section --> Click on `Use result types to display items`
3. Click **OK**.

Now you should be able to see value for `PostURl` Managed property in search results wherver it has value.

Note: Try to perform a full-crawl if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: You are a life saver Yayati! thank you so much for pointing this out. I was actually creating the 'New Result type' but was missing the last step to set the display template. Thank you once again. Cheers.